# How to understand log-likelihood for generative image model?

Tags: image-recognition, generative-models

I'm reading [a paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=BJrFC6ceg) on generative image modelling. In the paper, the authors compare various approaches by listing their "negative log-likelihoods" (see screenshot). What does this metric translate to in everyday language?

[image: Paper screenshot]